# Rails Assets - Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, asset-pipeline

I'm running into this somewhat obscure error when precompiling assets. I am using Rails 4.1.8, Sass 3.2.19, sass-rails 4.0.5.

Everything works in development. When I try to push to heroku it works, but I get this error on the home page:

[image]
Now I try this in development just to see if precompiling assets will work. I run: `AILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` it fails with this error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...mage: url("data": expected ";", was ":image/gif;base..."
  (in /path/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):6517
```

I tried to search the entire project for `:image/gif;base`, but it doesn't exist anywhere. Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: No I don't recall ever solving this. I think I ended up completely taking out the CSS theme I was using